# Installind Tomcat in windows server 2012

Tags: apache, tomcat, bigbluebutton

I installed Tomcat on Windows Server 2012.
It gives me below error when i try to test it by this address:             **http://localhost:8080**

> Bad Request - Invalid Hostname HTTP Error 400. The request hostname is
>   invalid.

Apache Tomcat is running in Services and when i run "**startup.bat start**", it works and give a success message.
That's a nice of you if help me.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Start tomcat services from windows services.

Comment: What does `nslookup localhost` from the command-line return? `localhost` should always be valid, but it's possible to break your own local hostname resolution...